# MS-Word Interop - Detect an AutoSave in process

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, interop, office-addins

This is an interesting one and should get the juices going.

I am currently working with a Word object (loading a document and working with it). There has become a need for me to catch the "AutoSave" event of word, sounds reasonably easy right...

I could use.

- Add event listeners on the `Save` and `SaveAs` buttons in the ribbon.

Would prefer not to, as I also have a ribbon with multiple controls and I'm sure there would be a simpler solution.

OR

```
If WordApp.WordBasic.IsAutoSaveEvent Then
    'Ignore, this is just Words, AutoSave
End If
```

- `WordApp.WordBasic.IsAutoSaveEvent`:  Which is working great, however, I would like to try keep best practices and latest technology (knowing that `WordBasic` is older than I am, I am hoping there's a newer way to do the same).

These thread(s) helped, using the old WorBasic, if anyone is interested in this route.

- [Using WordBasic.IsAutoSaveEvent](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/197e4897-06bd-4154-a5d9-87c3ae6ad629/applicationdocumentbeforesave-performing-a-saveas-how-to-delete-original-file?forum=vsto)
- [Distinguish Save and Autosave events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400645/distinguish-save-and-autosave-events-in-microsoft-excel-add-in)

In a nut shell, I'd like to find a way to detect if Word is running an AutoSave in VB.Net, even if it not a one liner (as above).

Apparently, what makes this harder is the fact that it does seem like the object model caters for this functionality (like they just removed it in .NET ([No Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414506/how-to-check-that-word-2007-invoke-autosave-into-word-addin)), which means, there may need to be a move involved way around this.

I do subscribe to the `DocumentBeforeSave` event if you should need to know.

Comment: This question has been booted around for a LONG time... Have you seen this discussion https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/392aa327-ed36-47a1-a6b6-394678679998/autosave-in-documentbeforesave-event?forum=worddev? I think that covers most of the other possibilities when you include the link in Christopher Frank's contribution. In a nutshell, though, the WordBasic approach will NOT go away as long as Word continues to support its current object model. This is what's running "under the covers"; the VBA interfaces base on it.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for some feedback, have you seen this thread? http://davecra.com/2013/04/26/updated-word-after-save-event/

Comment: Yes, that was the "link in Ch. Frank's contribution" I mentioned.

Comment: @CindyMeister I was wondering your thoughts on it (does it seem to be a possible solution)

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a workable approach.